# Cannot use AddRange on a list with an interface

Tags: vb.net, list

This is Vb in .NET4, but i have the same problem in C#.
We have to use interfaces for reasons I won't go into.

This works, but it doesn't use interfaces:

```
Public class PersonList
   Inherits List(of Person)
end class

Dim MyPeople as new PersonList
MyPeople.AddRange(SomeList)
```

I need to use interfaces such as IPerson and IPersonList because we use dependency injection to enable testing of these classes.

When I create an interface for PersonList, I can't see AddRange any more.

New version of PersonList using an interface

```
Public class PersonList
   Inherits List(IPerson)
   Implements IList(Of IPerson)
   Implements IPersonList
end class

Interface for the list:
Public Interface IPersonList
   Inherits IList(Of IPerson)
end interface
```

Everthing builds and works as expected until I try to call AddRange:

```
Dim MyPeople as IPersonList = new PersonList
MyPeople.AddRange(SomeList) 'BUILD ERROR AddRange is not a member of IPersonList
```

Presumably `IPersonList` needs to inherit from something that has an implementation of `AddRange`. But `AddRange` is part of `List(of T)`, which an interface cannot inherit from.

So how to I get my list interface to expose `AddRange`?

Comment: `IList` does not expose `AddRange`, so you need to add it yourself.

Comment: Don't inherit from list<T>.

Comment: In C#, I think you can get around this by re-declaring `AddRange` in your `IPersonList` interface, and then the `AddRange` inherited from `List` will satisfy it. But since in VB you have to have the `Implements` clause for interface implementations, I don't see a way to do it.

Answer (score 1):

You could:

1. Cast the `IPersonList` to `List(Of IPerson)`, then call `AddRange`. This will only work if all IPersonList implementations inherit from `List(Of IPerson)`, so it's probably not the best option.
2. Create an `AddRange` extension method for `IList(T)`
3. Use a loop instead of `AddRange`

Comment: This misses an important part of the question: they're using Dependency Injection to facilitate unit testing, and so for testing purpsoses MyPeople cannot directly have a realized type. It must be an interface.

Comment: Thanks for suggestions guys. Its looking like I've got to roll my own implementation of AddRange, RemoveRange, and all the other methods that are on List(T) but not on IList(T). What I'd really like is if someone (maybe from Microslop) can explain why the methods of List(T) are missing from its interface?